# SQL SELECT CASE throws an error with no parenthesis

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT CASE s.Country WHEN 1 THEN 'One' WHEN 2 THEN 'Two' 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Three' ELSE 'Your message.' END 
        ,(SELECT CASE DoYouWishToP When 0 Then 'Yes'  When 1 Then 'No' END)
        ,(SELECT CASE Housingoptions When 'rb0' Then 'Lease'  When 'rb1' then 'im lazy' when 'rb2' Then 'Rental' END)
        from tblSurvey s
```

Above script does work. My question is why the 2nd and 3rd SELECT statments need to be inside the parenthesis. ( ). And do you see any issues in my script?

If I Use below I get Error:

```
SELECT CASE s.Country WHEN 1 THEN 'One' WHEN 2 THEN 'Two' 
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Three' ELSE 'Your message.' END 
            ,SELECT CASE DoYouWishToP When 0 Then 'Yes'  When 1 Then 'No' END
```

Comment: It is a `case` expression not `select case`...

Comment: Q: Why do 2nd and 3rd "select" stmts need parenthesis?  A: Because they're sub-selects: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't.  Write the query as:

```
SELECT (CASE s.Country
              WHEN 1 THEN 'One'
              WHEN 2 THEN 'Two' 
              WHEN 3 THEN 'Three'
              ELSE 'Your message.'
        END),
       (CASE DoYouWishToP When 0 Then 'Yes'  When 1 Then 'No' END),
       (CASE Housingoptions
             When 'rb0' Then 'Lease'
             When 'rb1' then 'im lazy'
             when 'rb2' Then 'Rental'
        END)
from tblSurvey s;
```

Comment: Thank for the reply, but my main question remains, how come first select statement does not require parenthesis?

Comment: @SNash . . . Because it is not a subquery.  I understood the question as why the `case` statements needed the `select`.  They don't, because they do not need to be in a subquery.